# Add a color selector to a panel in Java

Tags: java, swing, background-color, jcolorchooser

I have created a pong game where I want to implement a color selector so that the user can pick what color they want the background to be. However, I cannot get the background color to change even though I was able to implement the color selector button. Additionally, since it is a panel I can't use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` so I am unable to go back to the game after entering the color selector menu. I also tried making a new `Frame` class, but it just opened up a separate panel and wouldn't change the color on the already existent panel. Help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        PongPanel pongPanel = new PongPanel();
        frame.add(pongPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        // new JPanelBackgroundColorTest();
    }
     
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.FlowLayout; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
public class PongPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private boolean showTitleScreen = true;
    private boolean playing = false;
    private boolean gameOver = false;
    private boolean upPressed = false; 
    private boolean downPressed = false; 
    private boolean rightPressed = false; 
    private boolean leftPressed = false; 
    private boolean wPressed = false; 
    private boolean sPressed = false; 
    private boolean aPressed = false; 
    private boolean dPressed = false; 
    private int ballX = 250;
    private int ballY = 250;
    private int diameter = 20;
    private int ballDeltaX = -1;
    private int ballDeltaY = 3; 
    private int playerOneX = 25;
    private int playerOneY = 250;
    private int playerOneWidth = 10;
    private int playerOneHeight = 50;
    private int playerTwoX = 465;
    private int playerTwoY = 250;
    private int playerTwoWidth = 10;
    private int playerTwoHeight = 50;
    private int paddleSpeed = 5; 
    private int playerOneScore = 0;
    private int playerTwoScore = 0;
   JButton button;
    JLabel label;
    
    
    
    
    public PongPanel(){
        
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        button = new JButton("Pick a color");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBackground(Color.white);
        
        label.setOpaque(true);
        
        this.add(button);
        this.add(label);
        
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        
        
        
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable (true);
        addKeyListener(this); 
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000/60, this);
        timer.start();
        
        
    }
     
   
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        step();
        if(e.getSource()==button) {
            JColorChooser colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
            
            Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick a color", Color.black);
            
            label.setBackground(color);
        }
    }

    public void step() {
        if (playing) {
            if(upPressed) {
                if (playerOneY-paddleSpeed>0) {
                    playerOneY -= paddleSpeed;
                }
            }
            if(rightPressed) {
                if (playerOneX+paddleSpeed+playerOneWidth<getWidth()) {
                    playerOneX += paddleSpeed;

                }
            }
            if (downPressed) {
                if (playerOneY+paddleSpeed+playerOneHeight<getHeight()) {
                    playerOneY += paddleSpeed;
                }
            }
            if (leftPressed) {
                if (playerOneX-paddleSpeed>0) {
                    playerOneX -= paddleSpeed;
                }
            }
            if (wPressed) {
                if (playerTwoY-paddleSpeed>0) {
                    playerTwoY -= paddleSpeed;
                }
            }
            if (dPressed) {
                if (playerTwoX+paddleSpeed+playerTwoWidth<getWidth()) {
                    playerTwoX += paddleSpeed;
                }
            }
            if (sPressed) {
                if (playerTwoY+paddleSpeed+playerTwoHeight<getHeight()) {
                    playerTwoY += paddleSpeed;
                }
            }
            if (aPressed) {
                if (playerTwoX-paddleSpeed>0) {
                    playerTwoX -= paddleSpeed;
                }
            }
            int nextBallLeft = ballX + ballDeltaX;
            int nextBallRight = ballX + diameter + ballDeltaX;
            int nextBallTop = ballY + ballDeltaY;
            int nextBallBottom = ballY + diameter + ballDeltaY; 

            int playerOneRight = playerOneX + playerOneWidth;
            int playerOneTop = playerOneY;
            int playerOneBottom = playerOneY + playerOneHeight;

            float playerTwoLeft = playerTwoX; 
            float playerTwoTop = playerTwoY; 
            float playerTwoBottom = playerTwoX + playerTwoHeight; 
            if (nextBallTop < 0 || nextBallBottom > getHeight()) {
                ballDeltaY *= -1; 
            }
            if (nextBallLeft < playerOneRight) {
                if (nextBallTop > playerOneBottom || nextBallBottom < playerOneTop) {
                    playerTwoScore ++;
                    if (playerTwoScore == 3) {
                        playing = false;

                        gameOver = true;
                    }

                    ballX = 250;
                    ballY = 250;
                }
                else {
                    ballDeltaX *= -1; 
                }
            }
            if (nextBallRight > playerTwoLeft) {
                if (nextBallTop > playerTwoBottom || nextBallBottom < playerTwoTop) {
                    playerOneScore ++;
                    if (playerOneScore == 3) {
                        playing = false;
                        gameOver = true;
                    }
                    ballX = 250;
                    ballY = 250;
                }
                else {
                    ballDeltaX *= -1; 
                }
            }

            ballX += ballDeltaX; 
            ballY += ballDeltaY; 
        }
        repaint(); 
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g); 
        g.setColor (Color.WHITE); 
        if (showTitleScreen) {
            g.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 36));
            g.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 36));
            g.drawString("Pong", 165, 100);

            g.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 18));

            g.drawString("Press 'P' to play.", 175, 400);
            g.drawString ("Press 'Q' to quit.", 175, 450); 
        }
        else if (playing) {

            int playerOneRight = playerOneX + playerOneWidth;
            int playerTwoLeft = playerTwoX;
            for (int lineY = 0; lineY < getHeight(); lineY += 50) {
                g.drawLine(250, lineY, 250, lineY+25);
            }

            g.drawLine(playerOneRight, 0, playerOneRight, getHeight());
            g.drawLine(playerTwoLeft, 0, playerTwoLeft, getHeight());

            g.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 36));
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(playerOneScore), 100, 100);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(playerTwoScore), 400, 100);
            g.fillOval (ballX, ballY, diameter, diameter); 
            g.fillRect(playerOneX, playerOneY, playerOneWidth, playerOneHeight);
            g.fillRect(playerTwoX, playerTwoY, playerTwoWidth, playerTwoHeight);
        }
        else if (gameOver) {

            g.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 36));
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(playerOneScore), 100, 100);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(playerTwoScore), 400, 100);

            g.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 36));
            if (playerOneScore > playerTwoScore) {
                g.drawString("Player 1 Wins!", 165, 200);
            }
            else {
                g.drawString("Player 2 Wins!", 165, 200);
            }

            g.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 18));
            g.drawString("Press space to restart.", 150, 400);
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
        if (showTitleScreen) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
                showTitleScreen = false; 
                playing = true; 
            }
            
        }
        else if (playing) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                upPressed = true; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                downPressed = true; 
            } 
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                leftPressed = true; 
            } 
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                rightPressed = true; 
            } 
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                wPressed = true; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                sPressed = true; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                aPressed = true; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                dPressed = true; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
                showTitleScreen = true; 
                playing = false; 
            }
        }
        else if (gameOver) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                gameOver = false; 
                showTitleScreen = true; 
                playerOneY = 250; 
                playerTwoY = 250; 
                playerOneX = 25; 
                playerTwoX = 465; 
                ballX = 250; 
                ballY = 250; 
                playerOneScore = 0; 
                playerTwoScore = 0; 
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) {
       
            if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                upPressed = false; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                downPressed = false; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                leftPressed = false; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                rightPressed = false; 
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                wPressed = false; 
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            sPressed = false; 
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            aPressed = false; 
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            dPressed = false; 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First, I suggest having a look at [How to Use Color Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html).  It's also very useful to have the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html) avaliable as well.  You will find that `JColorChooser` has a couple of [`JColorChooser#showDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html#showDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.String,java.awt.Color)) convince methods, which will show the chooser in a dialog for you

Comment: I would also recommend becoming familiar with [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) depending on how you want the UI to work

Comment: This might be useful to you: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ColorButton.java

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [How to Use Color Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html).

It's also very useful to have the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html) avaliable as well.  You will find that `JColorChooser` has a couple of [`JColorChooser#showDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html#showDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.String,java.awt.Color)) convince methods, which will show the chooser in a dialog for you.

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            JButton chooseColor = new JButton("Choose Color");
            add(chooseColor);
            chooseColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(TestPane.this, "Make a choice", Color.MAGENTA);
                    if (color != null) {
                        setBackground(color);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

I would also recommend becoming familiar with [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) depending on how you want the UI to work